# Examples of $e^A e^B \neq e^C $

Tags: matrices, lie-groups

Can anyone give me an example where for matrices $A$ and $B$, there is no matrix $C$ such that

$$ e^A e^B  = e^C ? $$

Comment: The left hand side is invertible, hence has a $\log$, hence a matrix $C$ thet satisfies the equation always exists. If you are restricted to real matrices the answer is a little more complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

$$e^A= \left( \begin{matrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{matrix} \right ) \\
e^B= \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right )$$

$e^A \cdot e^B = \left( \begin{matrix} -1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 \end{matrix} \right )$ is not the exponential of a real matrix.

(Note that any invertible matrix is the exponential of a complex matrix)

Comment: Can you suggest a proof that every complex matrix is the exponential of some other matrix? Or some reference?

Comment: @poisson: Reduce to the case of a Jordan cell $J_{\lambda} = \lambda I + N= \lambda( I + \frac{1}{\lambda} N)= \lambda I \cdot ( I + N_1)$, where $N_1$ is nilpotent. Take $t = \log \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, and $\log (I + N_1) =$ use the series for $\log(1 + t)$ that will have only $n$ terms. Then put together: $\log J_{\lambda} = \log \lambda \cdot I + ( \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (-1)^{k-1} \frac{N_1^k}{k}) $